# Group and then count in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do this in Oracle with count() and subqueries but i can't achieve what I want and I don't see any question with the same issue.

So I have this table:

```
ID          STATUS
---------   ------
1           A
1           A
1           B
2           A
2           B   
2           C
3           A
3           C
3           C
```

And I want something like this:

```
ID          A       B       C
---------   -       -       -
1           2       1       0
2           1       1       1
3           1       0       2
```

So grouping by ID and showing how many "status" of each kind are by "ID". Maybe I need a procedure? Can I do this with a simple query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  I prefer this abbreviated version:

```sql
SELECT ID, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS A,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS B,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS C
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to [pivot](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/) them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT ID, STATUS 
    FROM yourtable
) src
PIVOT (
    COUNT(*) 
    FOR STATUS IN ('A' A, 'B' B, 'C' C)
) pvt;
```

Comment: This was introduced in 11g and we're using an old version of Oracle, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.ID,
SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN C.STATUS='A' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) COUNT_A,
SUM(
    CASE
     WHEN C.STATUS='B' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) COUNT_B,
SUM(
   CASE
     WHEN C.STATUS='C' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
  END) COUNT_C
FROM YOUR_TABLE C
GROUP BY C.ID;
```

It is called "conditional aggregation". Please take a look on the above query if it is suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

The PIVOT clause is perfect for this.

```sql
select *
from t
pivot (
count(status) for status in (
     'A' as A
    ,'B' as B
    ,'C' as C
  )
)
;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a05fdc1d585875fd69ad6b4b981441ca)